# Split Attributed String and Retain Formatting

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, nsattributedstring

How can you take an existing NSAttributedString and divide it based on a predefined separator while maintaining formatting? It does not seem that componentsSeparatedByString will operate on an NSAttributedString.

My current workaround produces the splits at the correct points, but only outputs an NSString. Thus losing formatting.

```
NSData *rtfFileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSAttributedString *rtfFileAttributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:rtfFileData options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSRTFTextDocumentType} documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
NSString *rtfFileString = [rtfFileAttributedString string];
NSString *importSeparator = @"###";
// Wish I could do this
// NSArray *separatedArray = [rtfFileAttributedString componentsSeparatedByString:importSeparatorPref];
NSArray *separatedArray = [rtfFileString componentsSeparatedByString:importSeparatorPref];
NSLog( @"Separated array: %@", separatedArray );
```

Comment: You can't. There is no "all done" method in iOS framework. You have to do it yourself.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can make use of your split non-attributed string to split up the attributed string. One option would be:

```
NSData *rtfFileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSAttributedString *rtfFileAttributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:rtfFileData options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSRTFTextDocumentType} documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
NSString *rtfFileString = [rtfFileAttributedString string];
NSString *importSeparator = @"###";
NSArray *separatedArray = [rtfFileString componentsSeparatedByString:importSeparatorPref];

NSMutableArray *separatedAttributedArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:separatedArray.count];
NSInteger start = 0;
for (NSString *sub in separatedArray) {
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(start, sub.length);
    NSAttributedString *str = [rtfFileAttributedString attributedSubstringFromRange:range];
    [separatedAttributedArray addObject:str];
    start += range.length + importSeparator.length;
}

NSLog(@"Separated attributed array: ", separatedAttributedArray);
```

Comment: excellent answer this is what i was looking +1
i was trying with componentseperatedby but that is not supporting NSAttributedString

Answer (score 5):

In Swift 4, I made the function.

```
func splitAttributedString(inputString: NSAttributedString, seperateBy: String) -> [NSAttributedString] {
    let input = inputString.string
    let separatedInput = input.components(separatedBy: seperateBy)
    var output = [NSAttributedString]()
    var start = 0
    for sub in separatedInput {
        let range = NSMakeRange(start, sub.utf16.count)
        let attribStr = inputString.attributedSubstring(from: range)
        output.append(attribStr)
        start += range.length + seperateBy.count
    }
    return output
}
```

Comment: This will fail if the string contains any Emoji or certain other special characters. Replace `let range = NSMakeRange(start, sub.count)` with `let range = NSMakeRange(start, sub.utf16.count)` to make it work for any string.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an `NSAttributedString` extension that works in a similar fashion to some of the other examples here.

```
private extension NSAttributedString {
    func components(separatedBy separator: String) -> [NSAttributedString] {
        var result = [NSAttributedString]()
        let separatedStrings = string.components(separatedBy: separator)
        var range = NSRange(location: 0, length: 0)
        for string in separatedStrings {
            range.length = string.utf16.count
            let attributedString = attributedSubstring(from: range)
            result.append(attributedString)
            range.location += range.length + separator.utf16.count
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Comment: This will fail if the string contains any Emoji or certain other special characters. Replace uses of `xxx.count` with `xxx.utf16.count` to make it work for any string.

Answer (score 0):

In swift the answer is simple.

```
var string = NSAttributedString(
    string: "This string is shorter than it should be for this questions answer.",
    attributes: [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)]
)
let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: 120)
let newString = string.attributedSubstring(from: range)
print(newString)
```