# how to get components from NSAttributedString?

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring

I want to get components separated by specific string from an NSAttributedString. Is it possible in swift?

I am able to do this for NSString but I am not sure how can I do same for NSAttributedString?

Comment: Could you clarify what you wan exactly? It should be possible, but your question isn't clear. An example with values extracted?

Comment: let attributedString: NSAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "test string1\ntest string2\ntest string3"). Now I want to get attributed string separated by "\n".

Comment: In Objective-C, but should be translated in Swift: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31250074/split-attributed-string-and-retain-formatting

Comment: I'm not a Swift developer (more Objective-C), but a quick translation of the linked answer: https://pastebin.com/acuQ6jYe

Answer (score 1):

So to solve issue we need extension for the `String` that will convert `Range` to `NSRange`.

```
extension String {
    func nsRange(fromRange range: Range<Index>) -> NSRange {
        let from = range.lowerBound
        let to = range.upperBound

        let location = characters.distance(from: startIndex, to: from)
        let length = characters.distance(from: from, to: to)

        return NSRange(location: location, length: length)
    }
}
```

So input data.

```
//Input array with \n
let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "test string1\ntest string2\ntest string3")

//Simle String
let notAttributedString = attributedString.string

//Array of String components separated by \n
let components = notAttributedString.components(separatedBy: "\n")
```

Than we going to use `map` and `flatMap` functions. The main point is usage of the `attributedSubstring(from: nsRange)` because it will return 
`NSAttributedString` of the our parent `attributedString` with all effects.
`flatMap` is used because our `map` function return `NSAttributedString?` and we would like to get rid of optionals.

```
let attributedStringArray = components.map{ item -> NSAttributedString?  in

    guard let range = notAttributedString.lowercased().range(of:item) else {
        return nil
    }

    let nsRange = notAttributedString.nsRange(fromRange: range)
    return attributedString.attributedSubstring(from: nsRange)
}.flatMap{$0}
```

Output:

> [test string1{ }, test string2{ }, test string3{ }]

Comment: You have an array of `String`, not an array of `NSAttributedString`. And author seems to want an array of `NSAttributedString`.

Comment: @Larme correct. I want array of NSAttributedString.

Comment: `NSAttributedString(string:$0)` This create indeed a NSAttributedString, but if the initial attributedString had specific effects (not default), it's then different.

Comment: @Larme could you pls be more specific about "specific effects (not default)"

Comment: If there is underline effects on "test string1" on the initial `attributedString`, your `components[0]` won't have it.

Comment: What happens when there are two "test string1"s? Is `item` a `NSAttributedString`?

Comment: @Willeke you are right with string occurrence it will be bug